# how to avoid repeating multiple selects and inner joins and apply the where clause when its necessary?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my stored procedure, i am having several parameters which in case if one of them is filled some of them will be ignored and vise versa.

```
create procedure FlightReservations 
                @resDate date = getdate,
                @fromdate date = null,
                @todate date = null,
                -- few more parameters 
as 
begin
        if(@fromdate != null) 
         begin
            --it has more inner joins
            select * from tbl1 inner join tbl2 on tbl1.id=tbl2.id where tbl1.fromDate=@fromDate 
        end
        else 
         begin
              select * from tbl1 inner join tbl2 on tbl1.id=tbl2.id where tbl1.date=@resDate
         end
end
```

how can i avoid repeating the

```
select * from tbl1 inner join tbl2 on tbl1.id=tbl2.id
```

from my code, and apply the where clause on my result table?
what i need is have my result set in something like temporary table and select from the temporary table. but since i do not want to use the temporary table what is the alternative way.(because in it contains several fields and using the temporary table is not a good option)

Comment: Note that repetition might well promote query optimisation in this case, whereas `select`ing all 1st and filtering later might be a barrier to that. I haven't got a detailed knowledge of optimisation, though, so just an idea.

Comment: "using the temporary table is not a good option" - why? You should explain why you don't want to use it, to avoid people suggesting any other options that might suffer from the same perceived drawbacks.

Comment: so you are saying the repetition of the whole select ing is good idea?

Comment: I am wondering using a temp table is the only option ? also my result set has almost 20 columns, is there any easier way to do so ?

Comment: Only select the columns really needed in the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that checking against null should be used as IS NULL or IS NOT NULL, since NULL is not a value.

This should be what you are looking for

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 
INNER JOIN tbl2 
ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id 
WHERE (@fromdate IS NOT NULL AND tbl1.fromDate = @fromDate)
OR (@fromdate IS NULL AND tbl1.date = @resDate)
```

Comment: good but as i said i have more parameters to check. would you do this for the rest of the parameters as well?

Comment: good option, however it makes the where clause quit complicated

Comment: This works for this relatively simple where clause. If your where clause is significantly more complex, it might require a more complex solution.

Comment: Execution plans for this are unlikely to be optimal except if using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Comment: Agree, the execution plan seems to grow with each condition. Yet, as far as I can relate, he mainly compares the chronologic dimension, so it should be enough to create an index on the date and fromdate columns.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use dynamic query and build only the where clause based on your need.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '<YOUR SELECT & JOIN STATEMENT>'
```

then construct your where clause based on your options,

```
if(<CONDITION1>)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + '<WHERE CLAUSE FOR CONDITION1>'
END
if(<CONDITION2>)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + '<WHERE CLAUSE FOR CONDITION2>'
END
...
```

You can execute the query using any of the suggested options here,https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: dynamic queries are not good option, since it decreases the readability of the code.any other option ?

Comment: Also, again AFAIK, this is much less amenable to the query optimiser than literally coded queries.

Answer (score 1):

Use this scheme.

> `(Parameter IS NULL OR FieldName = Parameter)`

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
WHERE (@fromDate IS NULL OR tbl1.fromDate = @fromDate) 
  AND (@resDate  IS NULL OR tbl1.date = @resDate)
```

Comment: should be `OR`, not `AND`. Check the original code: the OP does not allow (or account for) both parameters being `null`.

Answer (score 0):

For the case demoed above, you can use a query like below

```
select * 
from tbl1 inner join tbl2 
  on tbl1.id=tbl2.id 
where IIF(@fromDate is NULL,tbl1.Date,fromDate)=IIF(@fromDate is NULL,@resDate,@fromDate)
```

Please note that conditions on both sides for IIF are same.

For definition of IIF, see <kbd>**[IIF on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213574.aspx)**</kbd>

Note that IIF is specific to SQL SERVER 2012+

Answer (score 0):

All you want is the WHERE clause to be conditional, which you can do like this.

```
-- First option
SELECT * FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
WHERE (@fromdate IS NOT NULL AND tbl1.fromDate = @fromDate)
OR (@fromdate IS NULL AND tbl1.date = @resDate)

-- Another option:
SELECT * FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
WHERE CASE WHEN @fromdate IS NULL THEN tbl1.date = @resDate ELSE tbl1.fromDate = @fromDate END
```